# Automatic window resize using Visual Studio 13

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How can I have a window resize automatically to fit the screen on the monitor, using Visual Studio 13 and C#.

Have an application which displays the main window from which you can call up (Fig 1) and individually display different forms to be populated and then submitted.

On some computers, the complete form is shown (Fig 2); however, on a few computers, only about 80% of the page is displayed (Fig3).  No side (up/down) scroll bar is displayed, so the users on these computers are unable to scroll up and see the rest of the page.  This is occurring on several computer makes and/or models and not limited to a specific make or model.  Is there a method to be able to automatically resize the page to fit the screen or to show a scroll bar?

Tried re-imaging an affected computer from scratch, but get the same results.  Image is coming from a central area, so don’t believe it’s the software.  Other machines are re-imaged with same central image without this problem.

Using Control Panel, tried adjusting the resolution for the monitor with no success, getting the same results.  Using a larger monitor does not solve this issue.

Had users use other unaffected computer, and they are able to get the complete screen.  Tried users from unaffected machines test affected machines and they are unable to get the complete screen.  User account profile is probably not the issue.

I am new to Visual Studio, C# and programming.  I am trying to maintain a legacy application and do not want to break the application 90% of users are able to see complete windows.  Open to suggestions.

[(Fig 1)  Main window
(Fig 2)  Functioning correctly, what window should look like.

90% of users get this window
(Fig 3)  Functioning incorrectly, 10% of users get this window.
Bottom is cut off.  No scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4oRU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To Use Scroll bars for this purpose you have to select the panel which content is getting hidden and in the properties choose AutoScroll : True

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeiwX.png)

Comment: The AutoScroll is set to:  True

Comment: Can you upload you project anywhere​ so that I can check what is the problem

Comment: Check it https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c/how-to-scroll-without-a-scrollbar-or-make-scrollbar-invisible?forum=winforms

Comment: Would I need to check the .ASP stuff to make sure the client piece has all the current plugins?  How?

Comment: I am unable to upload project.